# Azure AppFabric Caching development locally

Tags: azure, appfabric, azure-appfabric

OK,

My question is pretty simple, I am developing an application to deploy on Azure but I don't want to have to pay for any Azure services while developing.  There is the local compute and storage emulators, can you use Windows Server AppFabric as a stand in for the actual Azure AppFabric?

I want to be able to flip a switch that changes a release from dev to production and updates the pointers in the config files to the Azure account versus the local dev account.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Brent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use Windows Azure AppFabric cache. There's no local equivalent. You can use Windows Server AppFabric Cache, but it's not exactly the same thing.

With an MSDN subscription, you'll have an included 128MB cache.

Comment: Yea, I was afraid of that. There was mention about making them the same code base at some point in time right?

Comment: Actually just thinking about it, since I want to use the Cache service to handle ASP.NET session state I can still utilize Web.config replacement files to activate AppFabric for deployment but then sub it for SQL Out of Proc for local dev, not perfect but it's pretty close.

Comment: Yup - that'll work. If, say, you were doing direct puts/gets to/from the cache, that would be a different story. Using the cache strictly for session state is transparent to your code.

Comment: Perfect, I think this will have to work for now.  I should probably open another question but why would I use putters/getters to the cache instead of say calling the Application or Session objects instead? Any performance differences there I should be worried about?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recently released Windows Azure Caching (Preview) to develop and test locally

Link : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/